# Apply CSS on HTML.Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this is an old question that has already been answered on StackOverFlow. However, none of those answers is working here. I can't apply CSS on any of my html helpers.

My HTML:

```
@Html.TextBox("Origin", new { @class = "MyInputClass" })
```

My CSS:

```
 .MyInputClass
{
 width:300px;
}
```

Instead of getting a 300px width textbox, I get a textbox with the text: { class = MyInputClass }

if I try instead:

```
@Html.TextBox("Origin", "123", new { @class = "MyInputClass" })
```

Then I'll get a textbox with the text "123" but with the default width...

Comment: Where did you define css class?

Comment: Site.Css using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/Site.css">

Comment: Your second example should work. Are you sure another class is not overriding the width set by `.MyInputClass`?

Comment: Thank you HTX9! That was it! Insert the same sentence as an answer and I'll accept it! Many thks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whats wrong, because I tried both of your examples and they worked as expected.

Got:

```
<input class="MyInputClass" id="Origin" name="Origin" type="text" value="">
```

and

```
<input class="MyInputClass" id="Origin" name="Origin" type="text" value="123">
```

Is CSS linked correctly?

EDIT:
    Maybe you changed something, but now first example will make text box with "{ class = MyInputClass }" in it. Add empty string parameter in the middle, to make an empty text box:

```
@Html.TextBox("Origin", "", new { @class = "MyInputClass" })
```

Comment: Hi berzinsu, yes, it's perfectly linked. It's working on other parts of the html code.